# python match target word

Tags: python, iteration

For each target word, I want to check if the next words that appear before the next target word are corresponding to what I've set in a document. If match, I want it to output to true and write out to txt file. If false, write out false.

I'm using regex, but iteration way is fine

```
import re
re.findall("([a-zA-Z]+) " + tofind, txt)
```

Target and next words:

```
target word: document
next words: set is complete
```

Sample Doc:

> Document that I set is complete now. Document is great set. Is
>   document is great complete document set is complete. Document is
>   complete document is good but not complete.

Document appears 6 times in this excerpt, but I want it to return and output
the below to txt file

```
first document -> true
second document -> false
third document -> false
fourth document -> true
fifth document -> false
sixth document -> false
```

Answer (score 1):

Don't use regular expressions for this task, instead, string splicing will suffice.  An example of a simple way:

```
sampleDoc = "Document that I set is complete now. Document is great set. Is document is great complete document set is complete. Document is complete document is good but not complete.".lower()
findWord = "document".lower()
wordToFind = "set is complete".lower()
splitList = sampleDoc.split(findWord)
splitList.pop(0)
for position,phrase in enumerate(splitList):
    if wordToFind in phrase:
        print("Document Number", str(position+1), "-> true")
    else:
        print("Document Number", str(position+1), "-> false")
```

We split the text on every word that we're trying to find, sending it to a list.  We iterate over this list and if the important words are found, we output true, or if not, we output false.

Comment: @GarrettR Thats upsetting.  I just made up the words and so a lot of them were really really useless.  I've updated to use more logical variable names.  (Both the old and new versions work on my Python, so do tell me if this version also doesn't work).

Answer (score 0):

A solution with regex to ensure with word boundaries that words are not a part of other words (pre**set**, **now**adays, **document**ary):

```
import re

text='Document that I set is complete now. Document is great set. Is document is great complete document set is complete. Document is complete document is good but not complete.'

target='document'
nextwords='set is complete'

spat = re.compile(r'\b{}\b'.format(re.escape(target)), re.I)
mpat = re.compile(r'\b{}\b'.format(re.escape(nextwords)), re.I)

result = [True if (mpat.search(x)) else False for x in spat.split(text)[1:]]
print(result)
```

Obviously if `target` and `nextwords` start and end with non-word characters, you need to replace word-boundaries with lookarounds.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the stars index of all occurrence of `document`'s and end index of `set is complete`'s using `start` and `end` attributes of the matched objects. And get the expected matches by checking if the last index of next word is between one of the continual pairs of the `document`s.

```
>>> all_targets_start = [g.start() for g in re.finditer(r'document', s, re.I)]
>>> all_nextw_end  = [g.end() for g in re.finditer(r'set is complete', s, re.I)]
>>> 
>>> [True if any(i<k<j for k in all_nextw_end) else False for i,j in zip(all_targets_start, all_targets_start[1:])]
[True, False, False, True, False]
```